# p:ajax inside h:graphicImage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf, primefaces

I have problem firing an ajax request with Primefaces

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="token" value="#{clientBean.token}"/>
  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{clientBean.getParameter}" />
</f:metadata>
<h:form>
  <h:graphicImage id="id1" url="/images/circle-ok.png" onclick="dTag.show();"/>
  <p:commandButton id="id4" value="T" actionListener="#{clientBean.tag}" />  

  <!-- This does not work -->
  <h:graphicImage id="id2" url="/images/circle-ok.png">
    <p:ajax id="id3" event="onclick" onstart="dTag.show();"
            actionListener="#{clientBean.tag}" />
  </h:graphicImage>
</h:form>
```

The first `h:graphicImage` opens the dialog correctly, the `p:commandButton` triggers the actionListener correctly, but the `p:ajax` has no effects (tested on googles app engine).

**Update 1**
Changing the `event` from *onclick* to *click* was absolutely right (thanks BalusC): Now the `p:dialog` is shown. But still the `tag()` method is not invoked. I've updated the `xhtml`-Code  with `f:metadata` because there is one additional logging.
I think it's related to `p:ajax` and the invocation of the bean, I've tried *actionListener*, *action* and *listener* (from the documentation of Primefaces) with the same result:

- The app engines logs the invocation of `getParameter(ComponentSystemEvent event)` and Firebug shows this partial-update: `<changes><update id="otCounter"><![CDATA[<span id="otCounter">0</span>]]></update>`..
- The invocation of `public void tag(ActionEvent ae)` is not logged (also tried `public void tag()`)

The `p:commandButton` updates the counter correctly.

**Update 2**
I've removed the `f:viewParam` and `f:event` for simplicity and now are using `listener` and `public void tag()`, but the method is not called :-(

**Update 3** The answer of BalusC is correct, I have other problems when using it here: [JSF and p:ajax inside p:dataTable inside ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316486)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event name is wrong, it must be `"click"` without the `on` prefix.

```html
<h:graphicImage id="id2" url="/images/circle-ok.png">
    <p:ajax id="id3" event="click" onstart="dTag.show();"
        listener="#{clientBean.tag}" />
</h:graphicImage>
```

The `on` prefix of events applies only the names of the HTML element attributes which provide a hook for the event handler. They do not represent full event names.

Note the `<p:ajax>` doesn't support the `actionListener` attribute. It has to be `listener` and should refer to a method which takes [`AjaxBehaviourEvent`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/AjaxBehaviorEvent.html) as argument (no arguments is also perfectly fine). This is exactly the same as on `<f:ajax>`.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, now the dialog is shown but still my bean method is not invoked. (I've updated the question)

Comment: See answer update, `actionListener` isn't supported by `<p:ajax>`. Sorry, I didn't immediately see it as I don't know the whole PF vdl from top of head and assumed you to be right about that.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but this issue still drives me crazy. I've explicitly tested again `listener` and the method `public void tag()`, but the method is not called :-(

Comment: Are you sure that this is been placed inside a `<h:form>`? What if you use `<f:ajax>` instead? (only remove that `onstart` for test).

Comment: Yes, it's inside `h:form`. But additionally inside `ui:repeat` (where it works like a charm) and `p:datatable`. I think I've seen other related issues with 'p:datatable' and ajax requests and will look for them!

Comment: Ah if it is inside a datatable, you need to ensure that the datamodel is been preserved. Best is to put the bean in view scope. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked

Comment: How it is possible to bind a p:ajax event to jsf component like h:graphicImage ? an is there any documentation for supported event ?